# How to load multiple WebViews at the same time in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load a WebView and receive only that data.

I have 30 HTML files

Currently, I have been receiving data by loading HTML files sequentially in one WebView. Loading in order is too slow, so I created several WebViews and tried to load them. In the end, the WebViews are loaded in order.

Is there any way to work on `loadUrl()` at the same time?